# installing libtranslate and libtranalste-bin on raspberrypi

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

Is there anyway to install libtranslate & libtranslate-bin (the command line tool)
on the Raspberry Pi?

I have tried compiling it but I get many errors each time.
I have not been able to find anyway to get it working.

[libtranslate](http://www.nongnu.org/libtranslate/)

Additional Information: I have Raspbian Weezy as the distro but I will change it if it means I can run libtranslate.

Comment: [check out this](http://australia.proximity.on.ca/fedora-arm/15/armhfp/libtranslate-0.99-25.fc15/) rmp built for fedora, you can use alien to get that installed. There is no guarantee it will fly though :)

Comment: nice try, but that is an arm 7 package it would need to be an arm 6 package. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled the packaged by downloading the source for the Ubuntu packages and building them.
I've made them available [here](http://ice-os.com/downloads/raspbian/)